# How to wrap views in a Layout<View> control that uses a DataTemplate in Xamarin Form

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

In the Xamarin Forms samples there is a sample project called [WrapLayout](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/UserInterface/CustomLayout/WrapLayout/). This displays Image's (which inherits from View) in a custom Layout control.
This works great for displaying images in a wrapped layout, but I need to display images with a line of text underneath the image. It would be great if I could specify a DataTemplate some how. But I guess the reason it doesn't have an ItemTemplate DataTemplate property is because there is no ItemsSource property either.

Can someone please show me how to expand the WrapLayout control so I can specify a DataTemplate and bind to an ItemsSource property on the control (and don't have to populate the control using code behind)?

Or is there another control I can use that can display images in a wrapped layout that can display a line of text underneath each image?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Xamarin 4.0 (yet to be officially released) there is a control for that called `CollectionView`.

You can use the approach that you have mentioned to display more than the image, but it is made to work only on limited number of items and on large number of items it will crash the app (actually first it is going to slow down the app and may make scrolling unresponsive) so it is better to be avoided.

Comment: Cool. Thank you. I'll have a look at the CollectionView control in Xamarin 4.0. When you say it is made to work on a limited number of items. What is the max number of items it can display? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating an `ItemTemplate` or a `DataTemplate`, you should look at creating your own custom control using a `CustomView`. In your `CustomView` you can then add your own `Label`/`Image`/whatever in whatever layout you want. You would then add this new custom control to the `WrapLayout`'s children list (for example) like so:

```cs
List<CustomModel> listOfCustomModels = await GetListOfCustomModelsAsync();
foreach (var customModel in listOfCustomModels)
{
    MyCustomControl customControl = new MyCustomControl
    {
        Source = customModel.Image,
        Text = customModel.Text
    };
    wrapLayout.Children.Add(customControl);
}
```